# How do I view and collect real time GTFS from a feed

Tags: real-time, feed, gtfs

I have experience using the static GTFS files which define the operating model for a specific public transport network. However my city has just release a real time feed for the bus locations and other status updates for the network.

My question is, how should I view this feed in real time and record the feed into a database. The link to the real time feed is as follows: https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GTFS-realtime spec now includes code samples for parsing GTFS-realtime data in a variety of languages:

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/code-samples

It's a good place to start when it comes to parsing GTFS-realtime data in your favorite language.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install google's protocol buffer, then compile the gifts-realtime.proto with the protocol buffer to generate code which can then read the API source.

Answer (score 0):

Install Nugget Package Google.Protobuf

PM> Install-Package Google.Protobuf -Version 3.4.1

```
private FeedMessage _feedMessage;
using (MemoryStream protobufMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (Stream protobufStream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("", "http://gtfs.ovapi.nl/new/vehiclePositions.pb")) 
{
    protobufStream.CopyTo(protobufMemoryStream);
    protobufMemoryStream.Position = 0;
    _feedMessage = Serializer.Deserialize<FeedMessage>(protobufMemoryStream);
}
```

In **_feedMessage** you have deserialize GTFS RealTime Model to persist data into database.